# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta completa de archivo cargado en input type file con javascript?

Tags: input-file

Hola a todos existe alguna manera de saber la ruta completa de un archivo cargado en el input type file con javascript, hasta ahora lo he hecho con php, pero me gustaría hacerlo con javascript, para poder validar y retroalimentar al usuario a la hora de cargarlo con algún sweetalert, gracias.
Hasta ahora solo eh conseguido lo siguiente con jquery:

```
$('#file-upload').val();
```

y me arroja lo siguiente:

```
"C:\fakepath\archivo.xlsx"
```